# How to Foreach() list of lists?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

How to foreach this list to get coordinates (X,Y) of Two shapes from  json file:

```
public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where does your problem deal with JSON. Correct your tags please ;)

Comment: Damn that is a long list list list list

Comment: Call `SelectMany` three times.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. can you post the JSON file? that is some really nasty nesting.

Answer (score 2):

you can go with the following

```
foreach(var i in coordinates.SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany(x => x))
{

}
```

or you just box foreach calls, but i don't think a List of List of Lists etc is  a good idea,
what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: That's once too often, you only need 3 to reduce 4D to 1D.

Answer (score 1):

The old school way would be like this:

```
foreach (List<List<List<double>>> listA in coordinates)
    foreach (List<List<double>> listB in listA)
        foreach (List<double> listC in listB)
            foreach (double value in listC)
            {
                // Do something with double value
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers resolve your problem, but If you need only the inner list of coordinates, i would recommend extracting that information at serialization time (preparing the document upfront) or at deserialization time using `JSON.NET` or `ServiceStack.Text` into a more manageable structure.

That will prevent the nasty code with x foreach loops or SelectMany statements, which are also loops internally because that kind of code is algorithmic hell.