# Need to deserialize an array of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, json.net

Need to **de-serialize an array of array response to `List<Model>`**

This is my response from other endpoint:

"[[{"BillRateCardId":6992,"ExternalRateCardId":"cd77d9b5-a00e-4696"}]]"

Am using the below line of code to deserialize it to the Model but receiving the error "cant de-serialize that":

```cs
List<Model> Res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(Response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the data type that `List` is expected to contain, either by modeling it as an object:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var input = "[[{\"BillRateCardId\":6992,\"ExternalRateCardId\":\"cd77d9b5-a00e-4696\"}]]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<ResponseModel>>>(input);
class ResponseModel
{
    public int BillRateCardId { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalRateCardId { get; set; }
}
```

or by using `dynamic`, but then you lose static type checking:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var input = "[[{\"BillRateCardId\":6992,\"ExternalRateCardId\":\"cd77d9b5-a00e-4696\"}]]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<dynamic>>>(input);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized));
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used var externalRateCardIdsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(externalRateCardIdsLambdaResponse); But was receiving error. when changed my code to var externalRateCardIdsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Model>>>(externalRateCardIdsLambdaResponse); I cant access the properties in it.


if (Res.Where(x => x.ExternalRateCardId == (string)rateCard.SelectToken("ExternalRateCardId")) != null)
{Sourceid = Res.Where(x => x.ExternalRateCardId == (string)rateCard.SelectToken("ExternalRateCardId")).Select(x => x.BillRateCardId).FirstOrDefault();}

Comment: @karthikeyansivakumar - of course, it is a list of lists, you must loop through the outer list, then through each inner list. Do you know how to do that? If not, see e.g. [How to get elements of a List of Lists in C# using linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70432305) or [How to Foreach() list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27316030) or [Iterate over list of lists by the X coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55782963). If you are still unsure, you should ask another question, as the preferred format for questions is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: @karthikeyansivakumar - [How to merge a list of lists with same type of items to a single list of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1191054) can be used to convert a `List<List<ResponseModel>>` to a `List<ResponseModel>` if that is what you require.

Answer (score 0):

since you have only one value, you don't need the custom class

```
var data =  JArray.Parse(Response);
    
long billRateCardId = data.SelectMany(x=>x)
.Where(x =>(string) x["ExternalRateCardId"]=="cd77d9b5-a00e-4696")
.Select(x=>(long) x["BillRateCardId"]).FirstOrDefault();
```